# Query for rows with combination of fields and in statement

Tags: java, jooq

On a database level I have a table **product** that has two columns: **gtin** and **market** along with other columns.

I want to write a java code that would be transformed to the following query:

```
select * from product where (gtin, market) IN (('USA', 1), ('CA',2), ('PL', 3), ('CZ, 4))
```

On a `java` code level I have special entity `GtinMarket` that is dedicated to store these two gtin and market values:

```
GtinMarket {
    String gtin;
    String market;
}
```

On a code level I would expect something like:

```
using(configuration)
                .select()
                .from(table(PRODUCT_TABLE))
                .where((field(GTIN, Long.class),field(MARKET, Long.class)).in(gtinMarketList))
                .fetch()
```

After some investigation I was unable to find a way to write such a code,

I would really really appreciate any help,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DSL.row(Field, Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) for type safe row value expression construction:

```
using(configuration)
    .select()
    .from(table(PRODUCT_TABLE))
    .where(row(field(GTIN, Long.class), field(MARKET, Long.class)).in(gtinMarketList))
    .fetch()
```

This is assuming that your `gtinMarketList` is a `Collection<? extends Row2<Long, Long>>` as expected by the relevant [`Row2.in()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Row2.html#in-java.util.Collection-) method. The `in()` method has several overloads, so you can pick whatever suits you.

More information here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n